# How to fill remaining space in layout?

Tags: android, xml

I have these button like shown on the picture below, and I want them to arrange themselve so they begin at the top of the layout and end at the bottom, and also auto arrange space in between. How to do that?

[image]

My xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A2"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A3"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A4"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A5"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A6"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A7"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A8"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:text="B1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B2"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B3"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B4"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B5"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B6"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B7"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B8"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use weight. Some sample code follows.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="48dp"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button 2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button 3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button 4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code `android:weightSum="4"`will say to use a "weight" of 4, and each child here use 1 of that weight, a procentual value (25%). You could alter the weightSum and the weight of each child and thus giving each child a percentage width or height. Use 0dp to manipulate the dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. its working for me.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="8" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bA1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="A1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bA2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="A2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bA3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="A3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bA4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="A4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bA5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="A5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bA6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="A6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bA7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="A7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bA8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="A8" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bB1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="B1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bB2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="B2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bB3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="B3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bB4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="B4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bB5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="B5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bB6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="B6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bB7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="B7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bB8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
            android:text="B8" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dark_header"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Now it will look like
As i added Header and Footer also.

[image]

Comment: It's good, but it fills my whole screen and pushes out my bottom layer.

Comment: Now i edited my answer and added Header and Footer Layout. If its working for you could you please accept my answer. Thanks